# Enabling flood protection for correct calculation of hotness score

Tags: flask, refresh, pageload

I have a flask app that calculates the hotness score for blog posts. However the app is susceptible to calculating wrong scores in case someone continuously refreshes a page through a script. How do I prevent this?

P.S.-New to everything. So please keep the lingo a bit basic. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [cookies](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/quickstart/#cookies) they store client data or introduce logins then use [decorators](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/patterns/viewdecorators/#login-required-decorator).

Comment: Hey roy, thanks. I was wondering  if there is anything I can do at the calculation end?

Comment: what do you mean by calculation?

Comment: I mean, while I am calculating the hotness scores which takes notifications of views, likes, comments etc. as inputs, so a scratch implementation to prevent flooding just using the counts of these values?

Comment: Then you will have to incorporate logins and use decorators because  you'll be able to store user specific data like a post a user has previously voted on.